# E129 when calling the function by call()

Tags: vimscript

I want to call the function by its name as string variable.

Help describes that I need to use the `call()`:

```
call('ceil', [1.4])
```

But I am getting an error:

```
E129: Function name required
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the confusing part here is that `call` is a command and `call()` is a function.

After : you cannot simply write foo(). You have to write a (ex-) command calling foo(), like in

```
call foo()    or
echo foo()    or
let a=foo()   and alike.
```

So in your example try `:echo call('ceil', [1.4])` to see it working

Comment: The most confusing is `call call('foo', [])`